# Xamarin Forms - Recognize Postition

Tags: c#, forms, xamarin, position, visible

I want to make a comment entry that is only visible if the user is at the bottom of the article. 
So the app has to recognize when the user has scrolled enough, then a method should make the entryfield visible.

I can't find something like this on the Internet, so maybe you guys can help me.

[This one is without the entryfield and when the user scrolls down ...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsK6F.png)

[... the entryfield becomes visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGez9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a `ScollView`, there is a `Scrolled` event that fires whenever the view is scrolled and the `ScrolledEventArgs` contain `ScrollX` and `ScrollY` properties that allow you to know where the `ScrollView` currently is. If you compare `ScrollY` to the height of the `ContentSize` property of the `ScrollView`, e.g.:

XAML:

```
<StackLayout>
    <ScrollView x:Name="scrollView" Scrolled="Handle_Scrolled">
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="{Binding Article}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <Entry IsVisible="{Binding AtEnd}" Placeholder="End reached!" />
</StackLayout>
```

Code behind (`MainPage` is a `ContentPage` subclass):

```
string _article;
public string Article
{
    get
    {
        return _article;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_article != value)
        {
            _article = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Article");
        }
    }
}

bool atEnd;
public bool AtEnd
{
    get
    {
        return atEnd;
    }
    set
    {
        if (atEnd != value)
        {
            atEnd = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("AtEnd");
        }
    }
}

public MainPage()
{
    Article = "<put in enough text here to force scrolling>";
    AtEnd = false;
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = this;
}

void Handle_Scrolled(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ScrolledEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ScrollY + scrollView.Height >= scrollView.ContentSize.Height)
        AtEnd = true;
    else
        AtEnd = false;
}
```

That said, why not just put the entry below the article using the same scroll view? IOW just put the `Entry` element after the `Label` above in the same `StackLayout` and the Entry will just be there at the end always, but the user won't see it until they scroll down. Seems that that would be a simpler solution. Of course you may not be using a `Label` but the same applies, just put the `Entry` at the bottom of the layout that the `ScrollView` is scrolling.

Comment: Thanks that works fine! Ok, I will test the other solution also.